# Android Opencv exception on converting MAT to bitmap after processing

Tags: android, android-layout, opencv

My goal is to take bytearray at `onPreviewFrame` convert it into openCv MAT for some processing and later display processed frame in imageview.

My implementation of `onPreviewFrame` is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    Mat cvMat=Byte_to_Mat(data);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(cvMat, cvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12, 4);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(cvMat, cvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 4);


    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(cvMat.cols(), cvMat.rows(),  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

public Mat Byte_to_Mat(byte[] data) {

    Mat jpegData = new Mat(1, data.length, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    jpegData.put(0, 0, data);


    Mat bgrMat = new Mat();
    bgrMat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(jpegData, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);

    return bgrMat;
}
```

However `Bitmap.createBitmap` throws following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

Comment: Did you check what `cvMat.cols()` and `cvMat.rows()` returns?

Comment: yes they are zero, sorry my bad. But why cvMat is showing zero cols when data is not empty?

Comment: I have no idea what the `Imgproc.cvtColor()` calls do, might be the data get corrupted there. I would check the cols and rows before and after each such line just for finding out what is going on.